# How to position open node voltages correctly?

Tags: circuitikz

I am trying to label node voltages between two circuit elements, I can't seem to center the label (V(s)) vertically in between the elements. What am I missing here? I was trying to achieve the circuit in the picture.[image]
This is what I have so far.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Circuit 3}
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=2}
    \draw (0,0) to[short, f>^=$I(s)$] (0,-1) -- (-1,-1);
    \draw (-1,-1) to[L, l_=$sL$] (-1,-3);
    \draw (0,-1) -- (1,-1) to[isource, l=$\frac{i(0^-)}{s}$] (1,-3) -- (-1,-3);
    \draw (0,-3) to[short] (0,-4);
    \draw (0,-1) to[open, v=$V(s)$] (0,-3);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### update 2020-05-15

There is a [new pull request](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/400) for the pending 1.1.2 release that should fix this issue so that the code in the question will work out-of-the-box.

#### original answer

To "demistify" how the `to[open, v=...]` works: for historical reasons, the voltage placement in `circuitikz` was born with `european` voltage convention; so the short voltage labelling has some kind of logic here:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[european voltages]
    \ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=2}
    \draw (0,0) to[short, f>^=$I(s)$] (0,-1) -- (-2,-1);
    \draw (-2,-1) to[L, l_=$sL$] (-2,-3);
    \draw (0,-1) -- (2,-1) to[isource, l=$\frac{i(0^-)}{s}$] (2,-3) -- (-2,-3);
    \draw (0,-3) to[short] (0,-4);
    \draw (0,-1) to[open, v=$V(s)$] (0,-3);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: circuit with european style voltage]

...which is quite ok. Probably I should change the code so that the `american voltage` on an `open` follow what you had in mind (if you open an issue as a feature request on https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues I'll track that --- I am thinking about rewriting the voltage code), but for now, the label position is independent of the kind of voltages (`american`, etc) used. So your idea of using manual positioning is kind of the right one.

As a compensation, I can offer my way of doing it. I am using named coordinates and a macro for the voltage, and relative movement (so that if you want to change the position of the components you always have to change just one number):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}
\def\putvoltage(#1)(#2)#3{%
    \node[below] at (#1) {$+$};
    \node[above] at (#2) {$-$};
    \node at($(#1)!0.5!(#2)$) {#3};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=2}
    \draw (0,0) to[short, f>^=$I(s)$] ++(0,-1) coordinate(top) % change the -1 to move everything down
        -- ++(-2,0) coordinate(Rtop); % change the -2 to move right branch
    \draw (Rtop) to[L, l_=$sL$] ++(0,-2) coordinate (Rbot);
    \draw (top) -- ++(2,0) coordinate(Ltop) to[isource, l=$\frac{i(0^-)}{s}$ ] ++(0,-2) coordinate(Lbot);
    \draw (Rbot) to[short] (Lbot);
    \coordinate(bot) at (Rbot -| top); % vertically from top, horizontally form Rbot
    \draw (bot) -- ++(0,-1);
    % \draw (top) to[open, v=$V(s)$] (bot);
    \putvoltage(top)(bot){$V(s)$}
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: new version of original image]

Comment: Thank you for the information, I am more enlightened now on how to do these things in the future.

Comment: As advised, the issue has been reported as a feature request in the github that you gave.

Comment: @Rhandley thanks --- will track it!

Answer (score 3):

See, if the following scheme what you looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Circuit 3}
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=2}
\draw (0,0) to[short, f>^=$I(s)$,-*] ++ (0,-1) coordinate (aux1)
            -- ++ (+1.5,0) 
            to[isource, l=$\frac{i(0^-)}{s}$, v>=$V(s)$] ++ (0,-3)
            -| ++ (-1.5,-1)
      (aux1) -- ++ (-1.5,0)   
           to[L, l=$sL$]    ++ (0,-3)  
           to[short,-*]     ++ (1.5,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Voltage drop is moved from inductance to the current source

Comment: Thanks Zarko for the suggestion, but I wanted to put the label V(s) +/-  between the inductor (L) and the current source, more of inside the circuit elements. But if no other solution exist, I guess this could also work.

Comment: @Rhandley, from your sketch was not clear to me, to which element you like to add the symbol for voltage drop. Now is corrected (moved to current source).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the   `\draw (0,-1) to[open, v=$V(s)$] (0,-3);` in my original question. I just placed the '+', '-' and 'V(s)' manually at the appropriate locations. It's not that elegant but it gives the desired result. Maybe in the future I will be able to demystified on how the \draw  to[open]  works.
The modified code are as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=2}
    \draw (0,0) to[short, f>^=$I(s)$] (0,-1)node[below]{$+$} -- (-1,-1);
    \draw (-1,-1) to[L, l_=$sL$, name=L1] (-1,-3);
    \draw (0,-1) -- (1,-1) to[isource, l=$\frac{i(0^-)}{s}$] (1,-3) -- (-1,-3);
    \draw (0,-3)node[above]{$-$} to[short] (0,-4);
    \node at (0,-2) {$V(s)$};
    %\draw (0,-1) to[open, v=$V(s)$] (0,-3);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}  
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```